# Azure RM VM - The VM agent is either unavailable, or not installed, which may prevent VMAccess from running

Tags: azure

I have created a new Azure RM VM in a new resource group.This resource group also contains a new storage account, into which I have copied a VHD for the new VM. This VHD is a copy of one that works well on a different VM in a different resource group and location.

If I go to Boot diagnostics from the portal, I can see the VM sat at the login screen (Windows Server 2012).

I can click connect for the VM and download the RDP connection. My problems start when I try to login. Even though I try the same username and password that gets me into the VM from which the VHD was copied, I get access denied on the new VM.

At this point, I thought that wasn't going to be a big problem because I knew a "Reset Password" option was available from the Azure portal. However, when I browse to this option I see the following message:

> The VM agent is either unavailable, or not installed, which may prevent VMAccess from running.

If I enter details for the new password and submit then I get a dialog informing that password is being reset. This appears on screen for approx 20 minutes.

After such a failure I turned to PowerShell.

I ran the following script (with the variables set appropriately):

```
Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VMName $vmName -Name $vmName `
-Location $location -UserName $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Username `
-Password $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password -typeHandlerVersion "2.0"
```

This came back with the error:

```
Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension : Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension 'UPWORK1-VM' with handler 
'Microsoft.Compute.VMAccessAgent' already added or specified in input.
```

Can anyone please suggest how I could possibly login to the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This VHD is a copy of one that works well on a different VM in a
>   different resource group and location.

According to your description, you don't execute [sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/generalize-vhd) before your copy your VM. You could not start two VMs at the same time if you don't execute `sysprep`.

More information about `sysprep` please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb457073.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension : Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension 'UPWORK1-VM' with handler 
'Microsoft.Compute.VMAccessAgent' already added or specified in input.
```

On a Azure VM, you could not install two same extensions at the same time, according to the error, it seems that `VMAccessAgent` has been installed, you need uninstall it firstly. Please refer to the following steps:

1.Stop your copied VM.

2.Uninstall the extensions `VMAccessAgent` on Azure Portal.

[image]

3.Reset your VM password on Azure Portal.

[image]

Note: If you want to use your VHD to create multiple VMs, you should execute `sysprep` to preapre a [generalize VHD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/generalize-vhd).

Update:

> You credentials did not work

You could try to RDP your VM `\user` without domain. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506128/your-credentials-did-not-work-azure-vm).

If it does not work, you could use your new VHD and create a new VHD. Please ensure you should execute `sysprep`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Walter. The new VM is in a different Azure subscription and tenant to the old one. This is why I don't think I need to sysprep. It seems the VM can't be stopped (deallocated) if wanting to uninstall an extension. So, I started it then chose to uninstall the VMAccessAgent. This failed but I was then able to use the "Reset password" function. This reported success but still I am not able to login :( I provided a User name in the Reset Password screen of "BizTalkAdmin". When I try to RDP, I give ".\BizTalkAdmin" with the new password but I get "You credentials did not work"

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter for the comment before complete - trying for a carriage return!

Comment: No, if you don't execute `sysprep`. The two VMs on the Internet will be a conflict. On Azure `Reset Password` function is done by extension `VMAccessAgent`. You could check Azure Portal, if the extension fails, you could not change your password.

Comment: If possible, I suggest you could stop copied VM and try again. If possible, could you give me the uninstall extension log?

Comment: @tr0users Could you give the error information to your question? Like this [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28591782/Your-credentials-did-not-work-while-trying-to-RDP-from-one-Win-7-workstation-to-another.html)?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that out sys prep. In that case I guess I'd better start again! Here's the log, I think for the extension uninstall:"properties":{
        "statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"VMAgentStatusCommunicationError\",\"message\":\"VM 'UpWork1-VM' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage.\"}]}}"
    },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57875/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-tr0users).

Comment: @tr0users I have updated my answer, if possible, you could try again.

Comment: @tr0users Do you solve this issue? Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Sorry @walter I ran out of time with this so I deleted everything and resorted to a clean vm from the gallery.

Comment: @tr0users OK. I think my answer is helpful. If possible, you could accept it. It will help more people.